# Difference between Response time, Execution time, and CPU time

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, process-scheduling

I studied Computer Architecture from David A. Patterson and have came across the idea of **Response time**.

> **Response time** also called **Execution time**. The total time required for the computer to complete a task, including disk accesses, memory accesses, I/O activities, operating system overhead, CPU execution time, and so on.

In above definition of **Response time**, it is interchangeably called **Execution time**.

But, in Operating System **Response time** is one of the criteria of scheduling algorithm

I was watching a tutorial on all of the criteria of scheduling algorithm. Where **Burst time** or **Execution** time is the time process require for running on CPU

And **Response time** is the time between a process enters ready queue and get scheduled on the CPU for the first time.

In Operating System and Computer Architecture the idea of **Response time** in both cases are similar. But, **Execution time** is not **Response time** in Operating System. 
I also searched in google for difference between execution time and response time. Here what I got...
[Difference between Response time and Execution time](https://www.rapitasystems.com/blog/difference_between_execution_times_and_response_times)

Again,

> **CPU time** is the actual time the CPU spends computing for a specific task.

from David A. Patterson

**CPU time** concept match with the concept of **Burst time**.

Whole concept of Response time, Execution time and Burst time making confusion.

- What are the differences between **Execution time** and **Response time**?
- **Response time** and **Execution time** are interchangeable?
- What are the differences between **Burst time** and **CPU time**?
- **Burst time** and **CPU time** are interchangeable?
- **CPU time** and **Execution time** is interchangeable? If not then what are the differences between them?

Comment: Different people use the same names for different things unfortunately. So when David Patterson writes "response time" it is "response time as defined by David Patterson, which can be very different from "response time as defined by John Doe" and different from "response time as defined by Jane Doe".

Comment: The link that you provide takes "response time" quite reasonably is the time on your watch between starting and finishing a task. This is different from execution times. If you have 8 threads running for a second in parallel, that is 8 seconds execution time, but only one second on your watch. But if there are more important things to do, the system might spend 59 seconds not working on your task, then one thread runs for one second doing your task: One second execution time, 60 seconds response time.

Comment: @gnasher Can we call CPU time as execution time?